# How to find the trimmed mean of an odd amount of numbers?

Tags: statistics, average, median

For a 25% trimmed mean of 50 numbers that means we have to eliminate 12.5 numbers from both the lowest rank and highest rank of the set of 50 numbers. Should I round to 13 or 12 and then do the subtraction?

Comment: Does it matter?

Comment: yeah because it's in my lecture notes. How many elements should I subtract starting from the lowest rank and the highest rank.

Comment: Maybe it means that you set a weight of $0$ to 12 numbers and a weight of $\frac{1}{2}$ to one number ...

Comment: So, your lecture notes don't say what to do? What exactly do your lecture notes say? And why not just ask your teacher, who will surely know the answer, instead of asking random strangers on the internet?

Comment: Various software implementation seem to have slightly interpretations, perhaps the most common is mentioned in @MathP's Comment. Maybe see [this](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2005-September/079213.html).